# Does Improved Grapple Increase CMD against escape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, grapple

I'm learning the PF grappling rules, and was inspecting the `Improved Grapple` feat [<sup>(D20PFSRD)</sup>](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-grapple-combat---final).  It states

> You also receive a +2 bonus to your Combat Maneuver Defense whenever an opponent tries to grapple you.

And the grapple rule states

> If you are grappled, you can attempt to break the grapple as a standard action by making a combat maneuver check (DC equal to your opponent's CMD; this does not provoke an attack of opportunity) or Escape Artist check (with a DC equal to your opponent's CMD).

So, does the `Improved Grapple` feat increase the CMD for purposes of resisting a character breaking out of grapple?

Answer (score 1):

I would rule yes - but not because of the improvement to the CMD.  If that's all Improved Grapple said then the answer would be no (there is no such thing as "CMD against escape" - it's CMD as passive defense and CMB to actively escape).  But Improved Grapple also says:

> In addition, you receive a +2 bonus on
>   checks made to grapple a foe.

I'd say that means a +2 to CMB whenever you're actively doing any of the grapple stuff. And "escape" is one of the grappling moves, even though it's to get away and the way the rule is stated has connotations of wanting to engage your foe.